# Bind jQuery datatable values to controller parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a controller which returns a view model that has a `List<string>` property, and displays the results in series of text boxes in a jQuery datatable.  I want to allow the user to edit the list, and post the updated data back to the controller.  This is working correctly if I stay on the first page of the data table, but if I navigate to the next page and then edit one of the fields, the `List<string>` property on the view model is an empty list in the controller action.

Here's my view model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.Values = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

My controller actions

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.Values.Add("ST0001");
    viewModel.Values.Add("ST0002");
    viewModel.Values.Add("ST0003");
    viewModel.Values.Add("ST0004");
    viewModel.Values.Add("ST0005");
    viewModel.Values.Add("ST0006");
    viewModel.Values.Add("ST0007");
    viewModel.Values.Add("ST0008");
    viewModel.Values.Add("ST0009");
    viewModel.Values.Add("ST0010");

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    // I have a breakpoint here to examine the values of viewModel.Values
    // As long as I stay on the first page of the data table, viewModel.Values contains the updated values I type
    // If I go to the second page of the table, viewModels.Values is an empty list
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", viewModel);
}
```

Here's the datatable in the view

```
<table id="myTable" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Value")
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Values.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Values[i])
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#myTable').dataTable({
                'order': [[0, 'asc']],
                'pageLength': 5
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

The `<input>`'s `id` looks correct on each page of the datatable.

[Here is what an input control on the first page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SacKM.jpg)

[Here is what an input control on the second page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT5Q8.jpg)

I'm assuming the problem is that ASP won't load a `List` parameter to a controller if the submitted data starts from a non-zero index?  Is there any way of getting around this, such as looking at all submitted form data from my controller and manually loading each array element into the appropriate position in my list?

Comment: `id` attributes have nothing to do with it - its the `name` attribute which matters. BY default, the `DefaultModelBinder` requires that collection indexers start at zero and be consecutive.

Comment: I guess I could have my controller iterate through each value in `Request.Form[...]` and match each index's value to the corresponding value in the `viewModel.Values` parameter.  Would that be a reasonable way of doing this?  Is there any better way?

Comment: I am not familiar with `datatables` but some options would be to include a hidden input for the collection indexer to override the default behavior - `<input name = "Index" value = "@i" />` inside the loop

Comment: Another would be to generate the textbox manually without the indexer since its not required in your case - `foreach (var x in Model.Values){ <input type = "text" name = "values" value = "@x" />`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I didn't know you could modify the collection index mapping like that.